# How to add circle on ggbiplot plot using geom_encircle from ggalt package?

Tags: r, ggplot2, pca, ggbiplot, ggalt

Recently, I used `ggbiplot` package to draw the `PCA plot`.

For better visualization, I also added `geom_encircle` to get circle region on the PCA result.

**How, the problem I met is I don't know how to get the mapping color consistently.**

I tried several methods but didn't work.

Here is my example code, and **you can see, the color of these points and the regions are not the same. So who could give me some advice or solution.**

Very thankful.

```
library(ggalt)
library(ggbiplot)
data(wine)
wine.pca$x
table(wine.class)
wine.pca <- prcomp(wine, scale. = TRUE)
ggbiplot(wine.pca, obs.scale = 1, var.scale = 1,
         groups = wine.class, ellipse = F, circle = F) +
  # scale_color_discrete(name = '') +
  theme(legend.direction = 'horizontal', legend.position = 'top')+
  geom_point(aes(color = wine.class), size = 1) +
  scale_color_manual(name="Saturday",values=c("red","green","blue"))+
  
  geom_encircle(aes(group=wine.class,fill=c(rep("red",59),
                                                   rep("green",71),
                                                   rep("blue",48))), alpha = 0.3, show.legend = F,colour=NA)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could achieve your desired result by mapping `wine.class` on the `fill` aes. To apply the same palette to color and fill I added `aesthetics = c("color", "fill")` to `scale_color_manual`:

```r
library(ggalt)
library(ggbiplot)
data(wine)

wine.pca <- prcomp(wine, scale. = TRUE)

ggbiplot(wine.pca,
  obs.scale = 1, var.scale = 1,
  groups = wine.class, ellipse = F, circle = F
) +
  theme(legend.direction = "horizontal", legend.position = "top") +
  geom_point(aes(color = wine.class), size = 1) +
  scale_color_manual(name = "Saturday", values = c("red", "green", "blue"), aesthetics = c("color", "fill")) +
  geom_encircle(aes(fill = wine.class), alpha = 0.3, show.legend = F, colour = NA)
```

[image]

Comment: Wow，very thankful. You help me a lot.

Comment: Wow，very thankful. You help me a lot.  It's really cool! I am really curious that if the core code is aesthetics = c("color", "fill") ?? I have never meet this operation that like a miracle.

I have a small question that if there is something wrong with my code especially "fill" in geom_encircle?  I think it is ok though it didn't work.

Comment: Using `aesthetics = c("color", "fill")` is just a small trick. Of course could we have simply added a `scale_fill_manual`with the same spec. In general there is nothing wrong with your code. As you pass the color names directly you could have used `+ scale_fill_identity()` to fix your issue. But in general I would avoid adding the color specs as a vector. And as you see there is no need to do so. Always better to map a column from the dataset on aesthetics.